# Stencil Mask to render only part of a model

Tags: shaders, masking

I have a stencil mask shader that I use in Unity3D that I would like to reproduce the effect of in Blender.
[image]
Basically I have a smaller box in a larger room environment. The smaller box has a Mask shader and masks out the larger room except with the smaller box but I can see the larger room through all sides of the smaller room.

Where would I start ?

I am hoping to EXPORT this out as fbx or gltf - is that impossible?

Thanks!

~be

Comment: Start with searching for similar questions containing "object id mask", "object pass", "compositor" and "masking". Basically try to make the scene and use an object to calculate the mask and overlay that over the rendered image of the scene

Comment: Thanks @WhatAMesh, I will do and update

Comment: Nada... Searched all ...bump..